# Pessimistic Locking strange behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I was working on a module where I used pessimistic locking to lock a row.

I used the code below in a service method:

```
examSession = ExamSession.lock(ID)
println "after lock " + new Date()
......
...........
examSession.addTo.........(object)
....................................
examSession.save()........
.......................................
trigger payment.......
...........................
```

When I hit a button in 2 browsers(almost same time) to reach the service method code, I observed that the other thread(2nd browser) pauses after lock statement and does not execute even the print statement following it. It executes after 3-4 seconds waiting for the 1st thread to finish/commit the transaction. But I have read that in case of pessimistic locking only the db read operation are paused. It should have executed atleast the print statement. How does it happen ?

Grails documentation also does not specify lock() in detail. Please clarify.

Comment: What's `ExamSession.lock(ID)`?

Comment: ExamSession is a domain class(equivalent to hibernate entity class). lock() acquires a lock on the row having the ID specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExamSession.lock(ID)` acquires (or attempts to acquire) the lock. Obviously if it has been acquired already, the execution won't continue.

This is exactly what pessimistic locking is supposed to do, and it works exactly as it should. It doesn't pause **after** lock statement. It pauses **at** `lock()`, because it can't acquire an exclusive lock.

Comment: Ahh,,, you are right. +1 Thanks for reply. I implemented it for concurrent seat booking where a seat availability is checked, seat is assigned to user(first come basis) and payment is triggered. Suppose if only 1 seat is left, then only 1 user can claim that seat. Do u think its the correct approach ?

Comment: Well pessimistic locking will certainly keep multiple users from trying to work with the specific object. However you'll most likely need to check whether the object is still free after the `lock()`, otherwise another user waiting on the lock will "overbook" what was made by the first user. You don't want that.

Comment: @Kayaman @VivekSadh You essentially would want to read the `ExamSession` and apply the lock at read time to avoid the above problem that Kayaman describes.  In JPA, this is equivalent to using `entityManager.find(ExamSession.class, theId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`.  This you tell the database you're going to update the row, you want to lock it, read it, and return the row to the application.  No one can do anything, not even read it, until you've committed or rolled back your transaction.

Comment: @Naros Thanks for the info. 

Kayaman. Yes, after the lock statement, I did apply a validation and checked if the seatsRemaining is > 0 then only book else return and show message.